# Сохранение имени в поле ввода на js

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы введенное в поле ввода имя сохранялось после перезагрузки страницы?

```js
function valid(form) {
  let name = form.name.value;
  let password = form.password.value;
  if (name == "" && password == "") {
    alert("Заполните форму!");
    return false;
  }
  if (name == "") {
    alert("Вы не ввели имя!");
    return false;
  }
  if (name != "A") {
    alert("Неправильное имя!");
    return false;
  }
  if (password == "") {
    alert("Вы не ввели пароль!");
    return false;
  }
  if (password != "Q") {
    alert("Неправильный пароль!");
    return false;
  }
  if (name == "A" && password == "Q") {
    alert("Имя и пароль введены правильно!");
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.ru" method="post" id="form" name="registration">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Введите имя" />
  </br>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" />
  </br>
  <input type="button" onclick="valid(document.getElementById('form'))" name="submit" value="Войти" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить введённое значение в `localStorage` (или `sessionStorage`) и доставать его оттуда при загрузке страницы